# Azure Data Factory Copy Behaviour "Preserve Hierarchy" not working

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy data from one container in Azure Data lake Gen2 into another in the same Storage Account. I want preserve the same hierarchy with folders and subfolders but whatever I try it does only copy the json file and no folders.

As of now I have the target container set in the target dataset. Should I add something more (such as directory and file)?

Answer (score -1):

I have tested this for you and it can work, please follow this:

1.My container's structure:

```
examplecontainer
  +test
    +re
    json files
      +pd
        json files
```

2. Setting of Source in Copy activity:

[image]

3.Setting of Sink in Copy activity:

[image]

[image]

4.Result:

[image]